# Using TimeZoneInfo to adjust a timezone's daylight-savings offset

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, offset, dst

Below is the method I use that takes in three inputs:

`dateTimeInput` which is a string that represents a date.

`inputFormat` are my `format` strings like this format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz`.

`timeZoneStandardName` are unique timezone identifiers retrieved from `var TimeZoneList = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();` where the ID is retrieved via `timeZoneList.Id`.

I mainly used `TimeZoneInfo` to get my hours and minute offsets because it's very explicit as to what city/timezone it is, e.g. `UTC` is the input string.

```
public int dateTimeToUnixTime(string dateTimeInput, string inputFormat, string timeZoneStandardName)
{
    DateTime result;
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    TimeZoneInfo objTimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneStandardName);
    int timeZoneHours = objTimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset.Hours;
    int timeZoneMinutes = objTimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes;

    // if input format is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz"
    if (inputFormat == "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz")
    {
        result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeInput, inputFormat, provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
        int unixTime = (Int32)(result.Subtract(Epoch)).TotalSeconds;
        return unixTime;
    }
    else
    {
        // if other input formats
        result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeInput, inputFormat, provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
        int unixTime = (Int32)(result.AddHours(-timeZoneHours).AddMinutes(-timeZoneMinutes).Subtract(Epoch)).TotalSeconds;
        return unixTime;
    }
}
```

My second method takes in a Unix timestamp and a timezone specifier and outputs as a location-dependent time:

```
public string unixTimeToDateTime(int unixInput, string outputFormat, string timeZoneStandardName)
{
    // output format is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz"
    TimeZoneInfo objTimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneStandardName);
    int timeZoneHours = objTimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset.Hours;
    int timeZoneMinutes = objTimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes;
    if (outputFormat == "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz")
    {
        System.DateTime dateTime = Epoch.AddSeconds(unixInput);
        return dateTime.AddHours(timeZoneHours).AddMinutes(timeZoneMinutes).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") + toTimeSpan(timeZoneHours, timeZoneMinutes);
    }
    // output format is not
    else
    {
        System.DateTime dateTime = Epoch.AddSeconds(unixInput).AddHours(timeZoneHours).AddMinutes(timeZoneMinutes);
        return dateTime.ToString(outputFormat);
    }
}
```

For example, here is this method in a Grasshopper component for me to show you what I mean. `dateTimeToUnixTime()` is my first "clock", while `unixTimeToDateTime()` is my second "clock"

[image]

Given an input of those list of times and a timezone marker of EST, and given those dates (mind you November 2nd 2014 1-2 AM is when we get our DST adjustments again), this method theoretically should adjust its timezone to offset an hour.

I know that `TimeZoneInfo` supports DST because I can use the below method to show a `bool` of a respective timezone's DST status.

```
    var TimeZoneList = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

    for (int i = 0; i < TimeZoneList.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneList[i].Id + ": " + TimeZoneList[i].SupportsDaylightSavingTime);
    }
```

My question is, what is missing in my `dateTimeToUnixTime()` method that would allow automatic adjustment and offset depending on the DST conditions?

Comment: The Unix epoch is UTC based.  Since you assume all input is UTC based and the output must be UTC based, adjusting for UTC offset of DST offset doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: You are right -- I missed out an important part in my question. I apologize. I have corrected it now. The first "clock" you see above is a `DateTime` to `UnixTime` conversion (which indeed is UTC). The second conversion takes in the `UnixTime` with a `timezone specifier` so the output is timezone-dependent and localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your epoch starts at 1/1/1970, then we can use a `DateTimeOffset` `_1970` as your epoch, add the required seconds to `_1970`  and then use [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a date time in the specified time zone with daylight savings adjustments (if applicable). It is important to use a `DateTimeOffset` and not `DateTime` so that the correct offset will be kept when getting the string.

```
private static readonly DateTimeOffset _1970 = new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
public string UnixTimeToDateTime(int unixInput, string outputFormat, string timeZoneStandardName)
{
    var objTimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneStandardName);
    var utcDate = _1970.AddSeconds(unixInput);
    DateTimeOffset localDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcDate, objTimeZoneInfo);
    return localDate.ToString(outputFormat);
}

//1970-01-01T13:00:00+13:00
Console.WriteLine( UnixTimeToDateTime(0, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz", "New Zealand Standard Time"));

//1970-01-01T08:00:00+08:00
Console.WriteLine(UnixTimeToDateTime(0, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz", "Singapore Standard Time"));

//1969-12-31T19:00:00-05:00
Console.WriteLine(UnixTimeToDateTime(0, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz", "Eastern Standard Time"));
```

It is important to note that using TimeZoneInfo may not have [accurate information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397784%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about historical date adjustments, so if that is important to you, then you may be better using a library such as [Node Time](http://nodatime.org/).

Comment: I'll give you a reply as soon as I implement this.

Comment: Cool, that output is quite neat!

Comment: Oh yeah. Could you also tell me how to craft the timezone specifier, for example, the `zzz` format? Originally, I have my `toTimeSpan(timeZoneHours, timeZoneMinutes);` method that allows me to input the `timeZoneHours` and `timeZoneMinutes`. Do I just do the same thing expect for `localDate.Hours` or something?

Comment: NEVERMIND! It's just                 `DateTime localDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(UTCDate, objTimeZoneInfo);
                return localDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz");`

Comment: Hmm. For some reason, the two code snippets I posted above, still relays `EST` time despite having a `UTC` specifier: http://puu.sh/7Lwjw/787188a794.png This only exists if I use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz"`

Comment: Ok I fixed it with this: `return localDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") + toTimeSpan(objTimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset.Hours, objTimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes);`

Comment: I found this weird discrepancy: http://puu.sh/7LWVD/07b84f4231.png For the top example, it seems the offset increments an hour too early.. As you can see in the bottom example, the timezone decrements only on timezone changes. Interestingly enough, 2015 doesn't have this issue: http://puu.sh/7LXir/161993694a.png

Comment: You are right, there was a problem in the string output which I missed in my rush to get out of the door. I have deleted my other comments as they were noise, and have updated my answer which appears to show the correct offset--not sure if it will fix your one hour difference though.